# Closed ball in a normed space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed space and denote by
$$
B_1 := \{ v \in V: ||v|| \leq 1\}, \quad B_c := \{ v \in V : ||v|| \leq c \}, \quad cB= \{ c v : v \in B_1 \}, \quad c \geq 0.
$$
Now clearly $cB \subset B_c$ for all $c \geq 0$. What are some examples where the converse inclusion does not hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are none. If $v\in B_c$, then $v=c\frac vc\in cB_1$.

Comment: Since $c$ may not equal $\lVert v \rVert$, why can you write $v = c \frac{ v }{ \lVert v \rVert}$?

Comment: @Holden It was a mistake. I've edited my answer.

Comment: But then $\frac{v}{c}$ may not be in $B_1$, right?

Comment: @Holden Why? You know that $\lVert v\rVert\leqslant c$. Therefore$$\left\lVert\frac vc\right\rVert=\frac{\lVert v\rVert}c\leqslant1.$$

Comment: I am sorry, your are right. For a moment I thought of $B_1$ as the set of all $v \in V$ with $\lVert v \rVert = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Always they are equal:
$cB_1=\{  cv|v\in B_1\}=\{ cv:\ \lVert v\rVert \leq 1 \}=\{ cv: \ \lVert cv\rVert\leq c\}=B_c $